# Will there be an Appearance app in 11.10, or another standard way to change themes?

Tags: themes, 11.10, appearance

I've been testing out 11.10 and so far the only way I can change the theme is by installing Gnome Tweak Tool. Will there be a standard (i.e. installed by default) way to change themes and other appearance options? Just curious.

Comment: +1. Also note that installing Gnome Tweak also install gnome-shell, and as far as I recall it can sometimes cause problems with Unity...

Comment: rafalcieslak, I haven't heard of any problems with having unity and gnome-shell both installed on 11.10. There were problems with that configuration on 11.04, but that was because Unity used gnome 2, and gnome-shell used gnome 3. Now both Unity and gnome-shell use 3, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with the latest update to `gnome-control-center`, there was an option added to choose the GTK theme:

[image]

Comment: Better than nothing, but still missing lot of options (at least for changing icons).

Comment: Well, there **is** GNOME Tweak Tool, which is an official GNOME application, but as you know, it's not installed by default.